# Icon to indicate you can click-to-copy a piece of text

Tags: icon

My website gives a user their IP address. It is very common for a user to copy their IP so they can paste it into an email or game or who knows what. On the mobile version, I want to make it so you can just touch the IP and it will prompt you to copy it. This seems like a good idea so I'll probably do it to the desktop version too.

The text is normal H1 or maybe H2 text, it's not in a box or anything, but it is large. I'd like to put some kind of small icon right next to it to indicate you can click to copy. But I'm not sure what to use for an icon. Any thoughts?

My only thought would be something like an 18px x 18px -ish scissor icon. But the scissors is historically an icon meaning cut, not copy.

It's very much a "utility" website, so having an icon floating right next to some text isn't going to be much of an aesthetic problem. Function over form for this site.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried searching at the Noun Project?  See [example search](https://thenounproject.com/search/icons/?iconspage=1&q=copy)

Comment: Why do you need an icon at all? Just copy the IP address to the clipboard if someone clicks/taps it and show a notification that the address is copied

Comment: @BillyKerr I've never heard of that site but that's an interesting one I'll have to keep around.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Far more people will use the feature if theres some indication that the feature exists, and isn't just some secret easter egg. I'm not Apple after all! :D

Comment: Use the word "copy" in small text then